# Как взять переменную из JS файла и получить ее значение в PHP файл?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

Есть такой вот код:

```html
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
      jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
      jQuery("#user-region").text(ymaps.geolocation.region);
    jQuery("#user-country").text(ymaps.geolocation.country);
  }
</script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="user-city"></div> <div id="user-region"></div> <div id="user-country"></div>
```

Скрипт выводит в блоках информацию о геолокации посетителя. Каким образом можно получить , например, название города ("user-city"), преобразовать его в переменную JS и передать в PHP файл другой переменной ее значение ?

То есть => Получаем информацию о геолокации => Преобразуем ее в переменную => Передаем значение переменной в PHP файл для дальнейших манипуляций

Не подскажете, как это осуществить?

Comment: У вас в функции вы ведь уже получаете значение из блока user-city. Присвойте эту строчку переменной. И потом через ajax отправьте в php файл

Comment: название города можно получить вставив во внешний элемент идентификатор,например : <div id='user-city'></div>
а вся заморочка в том, что нужно обойтись без внешних элементов

Comment: jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city) - это город, который нужно получить?

Comment: Да, это город, который нужно получить. Я пробовал обозначать строку как переменную и пытался получить ее значение через $_GET, пытался обойтись средствами JS. Но я, к сожалению, совершенно не владею AJAX. Можете поподробнее рассказать про ваш способ?

Comment: Спасибо Михаилу и Андрею за помощь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743125/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5/743139#743139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"2.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"user-city="+ymaps.geolocation.city
})
```

[@Михаил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/256978/)

Источник: [как преобразовать внешнее значение элемента во внутреннее?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743139/191745)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
```

Это ваша строка с городом.
Помещаете её в переменную.

```
var city = jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
```

После нам нужно отправить переменную в php файл.
Тут происходит отправка переменной при нажатии на кнопку с ID `submit`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // send ajax
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST", //Метод, которым будем отправлять данные
            url: 'php/search_script.php', // Ссылка на ваш PHP файл, где будет происходить обработка
            data : city, // Отправка переменной city
            success : function() { //Если всё прошло успешно, то выполнится функция, которую вы пропишете. 
    }
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text) { //Если неудача, то вывод ошибки в консоль
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })
  });
```

PHP файл

`$_POST['city'] // Так вы получите значение вашей переменной уже на стороне` PHP

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, сейчас буду пробовать. Еще хотел бы уточнить у Вас, по возможности - а можно ли чтобы событие было не нажатием на кнопку, а , например, код срабатывал бы при открытии страницы?

Comment: Подправил ответ для вашего случая

Comment: Не получается. Скрипт называется 1.php , он должен отправлять данные в 2.php, а 2.php в свою очередь должен создавать файл и прописывать в него в строку.

Это код 2.php:

<?
$a = $_POST['city'];
$b = fopen('line.html', 'w+');
fwrite($b,$a);
fclose($b);

?>

Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В function() прописал alert('ok'); 
Подгружаю через АПИ , соответственно, только одну переменную

 window.onload = function () {
      var city = jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
  }

// В остальном все так же , как у Вас.
Может нужно что-то подключить в 2.php, чтобы он стал автономным?

Comment: Давайте перейдём в чат. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/68551/111?tab=general

Comment: Не хватает репутации. Заходите сюда: http://chat.rufex.net/room/30