# Как преобразовать внешнее значение элемента во внутреннее?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api

В коде `1.php` в текстовом поле `<textarea>` передается информация о городе пользователя на основе его IP-адреса, при помощи YandexApi. При нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" значение поля `<textarea>` передается в `2.php`, который создает файл `line.html` и записывает в него это значение.

Код 1.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
    jQuery("#user-region").text(ymaps.geolocation.region);
    jQuery("#user-country").text(ymaps.geolocation.country);
  }
</script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action='2.php' method='post'>
    <textarea id='user-city' name='user-city'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Отправить" >
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код 2.php

```html
<?
$a = $_POST['user-city'];
$b = fopen('line.html','w+');
fwrite($b, $a);
fclose($b);
header('Location: http://ipsay.ru/tools/iplogger/logdata/api/а/api/line.html ')
?>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы название города передавалось в `2.php` не при помощи формы, а автоматически при загрузке страницы. Проблема в том, что не понятно как изъять значение города и передать, например, в переменную, чтобы потом отправить в `2.php`. То есть нужно узнать название города `user-city` и передать его в `2.php`, без каких-либо действий со стороны пользователя на странице.

Пробовал разными способами через AJAX, но загвоздка в том, что непонятно как объявить переменную со значением города, единственный рабочий вариант - это создать любой внешний элемент на странице и присвоить ему `id`. И только после того, как внешний элемент (`<div>`, `<h1>`, `<p>` или тот же `<textarea>`) с id `user-city` появится на странице, получается передать его значение в `2.php`, а нужно обойтись без внешних элементов, чтобы передача значения `user-city` произошла внутри страницы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Как редактировать вопрос?
* Внешние элементы типа <div>,<h1>,<p> или любые другие, которым можно присвоить id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"2.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"user-city="+ymaps.geolocation.city
})
```

Comment: Михаил, вы гений, я два дня уже голову ломаю. Спасибо огромное Вам!

Comment: Да не за что.. Это нормально, тоже на таких моментах зависаю иногда)

Comment: А как в data передать еще и 'user-country' ?

Comment: Разобрался. Вот ответ , может кому пригодится:

data:"user-city="+"<b>Город: </b>"+ymaps.geolocation.city+"<br><b>Страна: </b>"+ymaps.geolocation.country

Comment: можно ещё и так: data:"location="+JSON.stringify({city:ymaps.geolocation.city, country:ymaps.geolocation.country})

Comment: посл чего в PHP: $loc=json_decode($_POST['location'],true);